# How to calculate the exact values of c and d

Tags: calculus

Draw the function $f(x)= x^3-4x^2-13x+10$ into a cartesian plane. If the exact length of that curve from point $P(5,-30)$ to point $Q(c,d)$ is $18$ (with $c>5$), I have no idea how to calculate the values of $c$ and $d$ using the formula $(dx)^2+(dy)^2$. How to approximate the exact values of $c$ and $d$ ? What is the values of $c$ and $d$ (exactly) ?

Comment: Set up the integral to calculate the curve length from $(5,-30)$ to $(c,d)$ and set it equal to $18$ and then solve for $c$ and $d$.

Comment: I mean what is the values of c and d ?

Comment: For next time, remember that entire mathematical expressions may be put between dollar signs, you do not need to enclose every single thing separately. E.g. `$f(x)=x^3+2x^2+5$`  is much better than `$f$($x$)=$x^3$+$2x^2$+$5$`.

Comment: Since $Q$ belongs to the graph of $f$ it follows $d=f(c)=c^3+4c^2-13c+10$

Comment: Okay, thanks Arthur : )

Comment: This link will help: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx 
And the limits are from 5 to c, and then for d you calculate $f(c)$ and that's it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The formula for arc length from $(a, f(a))$ to $(b, f(b))$ is $L = \int_a^b  \sqrt{1 + (\frac{d (f(x))}{dx})^2}dx$

So the arc length  from $(5,-30)$ to $(c, d=f(c))$ is $L = 18 = \int_5^c \sqrt{1 + \frac{d(x^3-4x^2-13x+10)}{dx}^2}dx$

Solve for $c$ and $d = f(c)$.

Comment: it goes to$ \int_5^c\sqrt{9x^4-48x^3-14x^2+208x+170}$ ${dx}$ $=18$ right ?

Comment: I don't know.  I didn't do it.  Let's see.  $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 8x - 13$.  $ (3x^2 - 8x - 13)^2 = 9x^4 - 24x^3 - 39x^2 - 24x^3 + 64x^2 + 104x - 39x^2 + 104x + 169 = 9x^4 - 48x^3 - 14x^2 + 208x + 169$.  So yeah, I guess so...

Answer (score 0):

I did an exhaustive manual calculation using wolfram alpha, and if I'm not making any mistakes,  the value of $c$ up to 6 digits precision is $5.61680$....